# Unsupported Platform error when running npm install

Tags: npm, windows-subsystem-for-linux, nvm

I am trying to run npm in a windows wsl/ubuntu environment. I tried to run npm install on a project I just cloned down from github and got this error back

```
npm ERR! notsup Unsupported platform for @next/swc-win32-x64-msvc@11.1.2: wanted {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
```

Oddly, running `npm -v` gives 6.14.14
While `which npm` gives /home/steve/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.4/bin/npm

Feels kind of like it's looking at two different versions? It probably shouldn't be trying to run a win32 package at all. Not sure how to remedy it though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library you're trying to install is declared as Windows-only as per the error message, but you're trying to install it on Linux (WSL count as Linux even though it's a "virtual" kernel). You should run it natively on Windows for it to succeed.

As for the versions, `npm -v` reports the **npm** version (6.14.14) while the version in the folder name of the path refers to the **node** version (14.17.4). Both are different normally, even though Npm always comes bundles with Node.

Comment: That makes sense. What made me think it was something with my node installation is that my project, while it references nextjs as a dependency, says nothing about a win32 version. So i'm confused why that would get pulled in

Comment: Maybe not in your project itself, but in a dependency of it, which makes the whole thing Windows-only. This is the error npm is showing, and it clarifies on which library it throws.